# using this code i m to implement payment integration system using debit card , i want to integrate UPI payment system in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, stripe-payments

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angualr-stripe-payment-app';
  paymentHandler:any = null;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.invokeStripe();
  }

  initializePayment(amount: number) {
    const paymentHandler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'pk_test_51LNufQSCtP1jbuyeViX8JQDKe2RViL55QgmABDrd30hZaGT678W2hYjmoxUqwMFqQjyJf84IoBsk1gxocY74Jbbp00wcDmkroy',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function (stripeToken: any) {
        console.log({stripeToken})
        alert('Stripe token generated!');
      }
    });

    paymentHandler.open({
      name: 'Aashu Kumar Jha',
      description: 'Buying a Hot Coffee',
      amount: amount * 100
    });
  }

  invokeStripe() {
    if(!window.document.getElementById('stripe-script')) {
      const script = window.document.createElement("script");
      script.id = "stripe-script";
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = "https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js";
      script.onload = () => {
        this.paymentHandler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
          key: 'pk_test_sLUqHXtqXOkwSdPosC8ZikQ800snMatYMb',
          locale: 'auto',
          token: function (stripeToken: any) {
            console.log(stripeToken)
            alert('Payment has been successfull!');
          }
        });
      }
      window.document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
  }
}
```

using this code i m to implement payment integration system using debit card , i want to integrate UPI payment system in angular, I want to stripe upi payment system in angular can any one share the code and help ?

Comment: What is the problem you're having? Can you post a stackblitz of your code and add information to your question

Answer (score 0):

You seems to use a legacy Stripe integration (checkout.js) and that wouldn't support UPI.

Today, for any payment method, you will need Stripe's latest integrations, either Checkout (redirecting from server-side) or stripe.js (direct integration on client-side).

For UPI specifically, you would need to reach out to Stripe Support for detail